# ASP.NET paging in div

Tags: asp.net, paging, repeater

```
<asp:Repeater id="repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <div id ="news">
             <div style ="float:left;position:relative;margin-left:10px;margin-top:10px;"><asp:Image ID="lblImg"  runat="server"  src ='<%#Eval("ImageUrl") %>'></asp:Image></div>
             <%--<div style ="position:relative;">--%><asp:Label ID="lblContent" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Subject") %>'></asp:Label><%--</div>--%>
             <div style ="float:none;position:relative;"><asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Description") %>'></asp:Label></div>

         </div>
    </ItemTemplate>    
</asp:Repeater>
```

How will I code paging on this site?

```
<div id="pager">
    <asp:DataPager ID="dpgSearchResultsPager" runat="server" PagedControlID="lvwSearchResults">
        <Fields>
            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ShowNextPageButton="False" ButtonCssClass="previousNextLink" />
            <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonCount="10" ButtonType="Link" NumericButtonCssClass="numericLink" />
            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ShowPreviousPageButton="False" ButtonCssClass="previousNextLink" />
        </Fields>
    </asp:DataPager>
</div>
```

This isnt working , and if anybody know write it.
And instead of previous and next i want paging with numbers .

Comment: i want to make paging in the first code.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: microsoft.net framework, version 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do paging with the help of a pager to your repeater as this is used for listview paging rather than as a repeater.

Have a look at this article that explain the steps to implement paging for repeater:

[Adding Paging Support to the Repeater or DataList with the PagedDataSource Class](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020121644/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081804-1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The `ListView` control is better suited to your needs - especially as you want number paging.

Scott Guthrie has a [great ListView and paging tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/10/the-asp-listview-control-part-1-building-a-product-listing-page-with-clean-css-ui.aspx) that takes you through what you want to do.

Comment: http://www.scottgu.com/blogposts/listview1/step25.jpg
So Joe this is the code  I need, right ?

Comment: Yes, you'll obviously need to wire that up with code. The ListView is cool.

Comment: IPageableItemContainer 'Name' not found.
What should I put in PagedControlID="Name" this statement,instead of Name ?

Comment: PageControlID should referene the ID of the ListView control.